# Iphone 4 CGPoint to Windows 7 coordinate system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, coordinate-systems

i'm developing this remote mouse app - windows server and iPhone\iPad clients. every thing works well on the iPad - i get the users pan gesture changes right into the server via UDP and then move the mouse by Java robot class. the iPad CGPoints that i get from panning in a view is only full numbers 1 2 3 4 5 (int) -> 3,5 4,7 etc.. - 
which is good for the windows coordinate system, so when panning from the ipad the mouse moves smoothly, but when i pan from the iPhone i get CGPoints with doubles and floats i need to round those numbers up and down so i can use them in windows coordinate system to move the mouse...

how can i solve this?
i need the coordinate system in the iphone to act like the ipad one...
ty.

Comment: Can you post the code for both iPad and iPhone? A CGPoint is a C struct with 2 CGFloats so I imagine you're casting the x and y values to int at some point in your iPad code.

Comment: Yeah yeah:

-gesture recognier callback-
CGPoint newP = [pangesture locationInView:self.window];

Then i get the delta of x and y:
newP.x -= previousLocation.x;
newP.y -= previousLocation.y;

I have this mechanism to store the previous location each time. After that i cast it to an int and sends it straight to the server